# Как не помещать Activity в стек?

Tags: java, android, activity

У меня в приложении есть `NotificationActivity`, которая вызывается собственно из `Notification`. И после того как она сработала, если пользователь захочет открыть приложение из недавно запущенных, я хочу открывать `MainActivity` приложения, а запускается `NotificationActivity`, в чем нет необходимости. Как сделать так чтобы она не помещалась в стек вовсе? Или можно каким либо способом отлавливать, что `NotificationActivity` вызвана из недавно запущенных.

Answer (score 3):

Для того, чтобы активити не сохранялась в стеке, ее необходимо запускать с флагом [`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(...);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
```

Этот флаг так же можно задать в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: Это работает, но не подходит в данном случае. В недавно запущенных все равно отображается `NotificationActivity`.

Comment: А существует возможность чтобы эта активность отображалась отдельно в недавно запуженных, а не ложилась поверх активностей приложения?

Comment: @DmitryVedmed, Да, существует. `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

Comment: Установил флаги, но все равно эта активность перекрывает ту. Отдельно не появляется.